# jQuery event handlers not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-1.3

I have a list of items on a page with a set of controls to MoveUp, MoveDown and Delete.

The controls sit at the top of list hidden by default. As you mouseover an item row, I select the controls with jquery

```
//doc ready function:
..
var tools = $('#tools');
$('#moveup').click(MoveUp);
$('#movedn').click(MoveDn);
$('#delete').click(Delete);
..
$('li.item').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).prepend(tools);
});
```

This works great in Firefox .. the tools move into the current row, and the click events call the ajax functions. However, in IE6 and IE7 .. no click occurs. I tried unbinding on mouseout and rebinding on each mouseover .. to no avail.

I also looked into various reasons outside of javascript (e.g. transparent png conflicts, z-index, position:absolute) .. also no solution found.

I eventually needed to add a tools row to each item and show/hide on mouse over/out. Works just as well -- the only downer is that I have much more 'tools' markup on my page.

Does anyone know why IE ignores/drops/kills the mouse events once the objects are moved (using prepend)? And why rebinding the event afterwards also has no effect? Kept me annoyed for almost 2 hours before I gave up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE will lose events depending on how you are adding things to the DOM.

```
var ele = $("#itemtocopy");

$("#someotheritem").append( ele ); // Will not work and will lose events

$("#someotheritem").append( ele.clone(true) );
```

I would also recommend using .live() on the click events to simplify your code a little. Mouseover/out is not supported by live yet. http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Comment: Fair enough, as I said the events are lost. But why would I not be able to add the events to the new objects?

Also, I do not want to copy the objects, just move them. Again, if the events are lost, I should still be able to re-bind.

Furthermore, if the events are not firing, you would think the href link would be followed.. this does not happen either .. nothing happens AT ALL.

Comment: It is a limitation/bug of IE's DOM and sadly, you just have to live with it for now if you are going to support IE. As far as moving the element, you cannot move it without cloning first or you will create what is called a circular reference. Even when moving you need to  var cloned = $("#element").clone(true); $("#element").remove(); $("newplace").append(cloned);

Answer (score 2):

I just spent the whole day troubleshooting events not triggering on items appended to the DOM, (IE7, jQuery 1.4.1) and it wasn't because I needed to use live() (though, good to know, Chad), nor was it because I needed to clone the items.

It was because I was selecting anchor tags that had a "#" in them like so:

```
var myitem = $('a[href=#top]');
```

My solution was to use the "Attribute Contains Selector" like so:

```
var myitem = $('a[href*=top]');
```

Fortunately I have enough control over everything that it won't likely break in the future. This isn't technically related to appended objects, but hopefully it saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem. trying to use .ready to load a div on the initial page load. 
works well in FF , but not ie7.

i have found a hack that seems to get around this.

I have load call a callback, divLoaded().

In divLoaded i check the $('#targetdiv').innerText.length < 50 or whatever you think will indicate that it didnt load. If I detect that case, i simply call the function taht loads that div again.

Oddly enough, i also add a '.' to the innerText before i recall the ajax function. It seems taht sometimes we go through 3 or 4 loops before the ajax load finally takes.

This leads me to think that document.ready works pretty flawlessly in IE7, which seems to dispel a bit of a myth that it is unreliable. What really 'seems' to be happening is that .load is a little bit flakey and doesnt work well when the page is just loaded.

I am still a bit green w/ all the jQuery stuff, so take this w/ a grain of salt. Interested to hear anyone's take on my little hypothesis.

cheers

greg